# SNIMatcher not returning correct certificate

Tags: java-8, sni

I have a server and I've added an SNIMatcher based on this example

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SNIExamples

```
SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = ...;
SNIMatcher matcher = SNIHostName.createSNIMatcher("www\\.example\\.(com|org)");
Collection<SNIMatcher> matchers = new ArrayList<>(1);
matchers.add(matcher);

SSLParameters params = sslServerSocket.getSSLParameters();
params.setSNIMatchers(matchers);
sslServerSocket.setSSLParameters(params);
```

I've added example.com and example.org in my hosts file to be 127.0.0.1

When I go to example.com and example.org they both get the same localhost certificate (I've created a separate certificate for example.org)

My question is what's the correct way to attach a SNIMatcher

do I need to create a separate matcher for each virtual host that has its own certificate? (I did that but I got an IllegalArgumentException because both hosts had the same type 0 (StandardConstants.SNI_HOST_NAME)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLParameters.html#setSNIMatchers-java.util.Collection-

so I changed the way I am attaching and just did it the way example does (com|org) but it's returning the same certificate for both. Just wondering what's the correct way?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with the x509 stuff (distinguished name) in the certs of the keys in the keystore used for the sslcontext that issued the sslserversocketfactory.

Choosing the key and presenting the x509 cert (given the "merely accepted" sni hostname) has to do with some DN in the x509 because that's the only mapping knowledge available. The host mapping is certainly not done with the keystore alias! The mapping information from the keystore has to be in the cert, a hostname that a certificate authority has signed.

AFAIK, the SNI server-side mechanism doesn't do that key selection, it only restricts the hostnames allowed for the entire keystore/keymanager hooked up.

PS: If you wanted to switch keystores, then you would have to essentially build an sslcontext with a X509KeyManager of your own that can provide all the material of all key stores. You would likely wrap an array of key managers out of a KeyManagerFactory... and the support ends here for me because it gets ugly too fast for what I recall!